# "some problems he recently had" vs "that he recently had some problems"

Tags: grammaticality, subordinate-clauses

Which one is correct?

> He is talking about **some problems he recently had** with his friend.

> He is talking about **that he recently had some problems** with his friend.

Comment: What do you mean, "What field"?

Comment: What should I study to understand the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#1 -- the syntax is OK and the meaning is clear.

#2 -- the bolded phrase is OK, but it does not fit with the sentence start. It could follow "He *said* that..." or "He *explained* that..." (a past tense verb).

Comment: I should have mentioned another phrasing that is close to #2 and is OK: "He is talking about *the fact that* he recently had some problems with a friend."

Comment: You can always edit your answer to improve it. Also, could you explain why the second sentence is wrong, rather than just how to correct it? The clause, "*that he recently had some problems with his friend*" acts a noun, and it follows a preposition, "about", so it seems it should be grammatical, but it's not.